# Determine in how many categories users are logged per time window unit

Tags: python, pandas, database

I have a log of users and in which category it is logged. Users can be logged in multiple categories. I would like to determine which users are logged in multiple categories. The log is kinda long so preferably it would be sorted on users on top that have been logged in most categories.

| user | category |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | A |
| 3 | A |
| 3 | B |

Currently using group_by I'm only able to show the counts, but not the names of the categories. Most existing questions are usually asking it the other way around (e.g. how many users are there in a category). I would like to do something like this:

| user | categories | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A, B | 2 |
| 2 | A | 1 |
| 3 | A, B | 2 |

To make it more complicated, I would like to determine the same but then I would also like to know if users are logged in multiple categories within specific time windows (e.g. 5 minutes):

| timestamp | user | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-12 13:00:00 | 1 | A |
| 2021-12-12 13:06:00 | 1 | B |
| 2021-12-12 13:08:00 | 2 | A |
| 2021-12-12 13:09:00 | 1 | B |
| 2021-12-12 13:14:00 | 3 | A |
| 2021-12-12 13:15:00 | 3 | B |
| 2021-12-12 13:15:00 | 3 | A |
| 2021-12-12 13:15:00 | 1 | B |

I would like something like below (but open to different display methods) so the categories per user are kinda binned per time-window (5 min in this example):

| timestamp | user | categories | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-12 13:00:00 | 1 | A | 1 |
| 2021-12-12 13:05:00 | 1 | B | 1 |
| 2021-12-12 13:05:00 | 2 | A | 1 |
| 2021-12-12 13:05:00 | 1 | B | 1 |
| 2021-12-12 13:10:00 | 3 | A | 1 |
| 2021-12-12 13:15:00 | 3 | B, A | 2 |
| 2021-12-12 13:15:00 | 1 | B | 1 |

I tried all kinds of things with combinations .resample, groub_by and .cumsum without any luck. I hope the examples make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) by column `user`:

```
df1 = (df.groupby('user', as_index=False)
         .agg(categories=('category', ','.join), counts=('category', 'size')))
print (df1)
   user categories  counts
0     1        A,B       2
1     2          A       1
2     3        A,B       2
```

For second my output is different - is used [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) with `freq='5min'`:

```
df2 = (df.groupby(['user', pd.Grouper(freq='5min', key='timestamp')])
         .agg(categories=('category', ','.join), counts=('category', 'size'))
         .reset_index()
         .sort_values('timestamp', ignore_index=True))
print (df2)
   user           timestamp categories  counts
0     1 2021-12-12 13:00:00          A       1
1     1 2021-12-12 13:05:00        B,B       2
2     2 2021-12-12 13:05:00          A       1
3     3 2021-12-12 13:10:00          A       1
4     1 2021-12-12 13:15:00          B       1
5     3 2021-12-12 13:15:00        B,A       2
```

EDIT:

```
df3 = (df.groupby(['user', pd.Grouper(freq='5min', key='timestamp')])
         .agg(categories=('category', lambda x: ','.join(set(x))), 
              counts=('category', 'nunique'))
         .reset_index()
         .sort_values('timestamp', ignore_index=True))
print (df3)
   user           timestamp categories  counts
0     1 2021-12-12 13:00:00          A       1
1     1 2021-12-12 13:05:00          B       1
2     2 2021-12-12 13:05:00          A       1
3     3 2021-12-12 13:10:00          A       1
4     1 2021-12-12 13:15:00          B       1
5     3 2021-12-12 13:15:00        B,A       2
```

Comment: hero! thanks for the quick help and good to learn about the Grouper function.

Comment: One limitation though, currently the logic joins and counts all categories a user is in, but it also counts the non-unique ones. I need in the categories and counts only the unique categories. So categories B, B with counts 2, should be Categories B, count 1.

Comment: @Mick - order is important in joined values?

Comment: I never knew about the Python 'set()' function. Order is not important. Thanks again.